# Linking GSL statically using Cmake

Tags: cmake, compilation, gsl, pybind11

I'm linking GNU GSL with a pybind11 module. It works if GSL is linked as a shared library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(st)

# Paths
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

# Packages
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
find_package(GSL REQUIRED)

# Includes
set(DIRS ${GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GSLCBLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${DIRS})

# Python module
pybind11_add_module(st src/st.cpp)

# Libraries
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${GSL_LIBRARIES} ${GSLCBLAS_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(st PRIVATE ${LIBS})
```

How can I link it statically? I've tried a lot of different options but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a problem description. Note, that unlike to a shared library, a static library doesn't track its dependencies. So, if a GSL library uses some other libraries, then you need to link with them manually. One may suggest that `find_package` should care of the library's dependencies, but most of existent `FindXXX.cmake` scripts do not do that.

Comment: I have the exact same question.  I tried `cmake -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-static" -DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES=".a" ..` but to no avail.  GSL is still linked dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that CMake resets the contents of `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` during the `PROJECT` statement, see the file *Modules/CMakeGenericSystem.cmake* in the installation of CMake. For example, this *CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

message("CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES = ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}")
project(st)
message("CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES = ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}")

set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")  # <--- this is needed to replace the default

# Packages
find_package(GSL REQUIRED)

# Libraries
message("Libraries: ${GSL_LIBRARIES} ${GSLCBLAS_LIBRARIES}")
```

when executed as

```
cmake -D CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES=".a" .
```

produces the output

```
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES = .a
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES = .so;.a
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.6.3") 
-- Found GSL: /opt/gsl-2.6/include (found version "2.6") 
Libraries: /opt/gsl-2.6/lib64/libgsl.a;/opt/gsl-2.6/lib64/libgslcblas.a 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Apparently, a possible solution seems to be to redefine the variable (by manually modifying the script) right after the `PROJECT` statement, as done in the above sample code.

Comment: I would recommend recording the previous value of `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` and then storing it back after `find_package(GSL REQUIRED)` otherwise it can lead to problems for other targets found using `find_package(...)` after this. Also, please note that this answer assumes that the static library for gsl either doesn't depend on any additional deps or the `find_package()` provides the info for you (which is not always necessary for a shared library target)